# Draw a gradient without banding (dithered) on iOS

Tags: ios, core-graphics, gradient

Is there a way to dynamically draw a dithered gradient on iOS? I'm currently using `CGContextDrawLinearGradient`, but it produces a noticeable banding effect.

Comment: What are your gradient colour positions? I have noticed this with positions close to one another or small textures.

Comment: Positions 1.0f and 0.0f, colors black with alpha 0 and black with alpha 0.6f. The gradient is vertical, about 50 pixels high.